# Optimizing sql query to search in more than 10 million record

Tags: mysql, innodb, optimization

I have a `SELECT` query to search a large table which contains more than 10 million records. I wish to optimize this query for reduce CPU load and get faster response:

```
$query=    'SELECT  DISTINCT id_order AS id_order, marketplace AS 
marketplace, 
date_add AS date_add, message AS message from
(
SELECT o.id_order AS id_order, o.date_add AS date_add, o.current_state AS 
state, lo.marketplace AS marketplace, lo.carrier AS carrier, lo.message 
AS message
                    FROM   ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'orders o
                    LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'lengow_orders` lo ON ( 
o.id_order =  lo.id_order )
                    WHERE marketplace NOT IN(\'pixplace\') OR marketplace 
IS NULL                        
            UNION ALL
                SELECT oo.id_order AS id_order, oo.date_add AS date_add, 
loo.marketplace AS marketplace, loo.carrier AS carrier, oo.current_state 
AS state, loo.message AS message
                    FROM    ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'orders oo
                    RIGHT JOIN ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'lengow_orders loo ON ( 
oo.id_order = loo.id_order  )
                    ) AS id_order
            WHERE date_add > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), interval 3 DAY)
            AND (carrier IS NULL OR carrier!=\'shipped by cdiscount\')
            AND id_order NOT IN ('.implode(',', getOrderDuplicated()).')
            AND state = 2    
            AND id_order IN (' . implode(',', $ids_order_to_recalculate) 
. ') ORDER BY id_order DESC';
```

i puted getOrderDuplicated() and $ids_order_to_recalculate in implode to search id_order, i'm looking for improvement this code.

sql query without code php :

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_order AS id_order, marketplace AS marketplace, date_add AS date_add, message AS message 
FROM ( 
    SELECT o.id_order AS id_order
         , o.date_add AS date_add
         , o.current_state AS state
         , lo.marketplace AS marketplace
         , lo.carrier AS carrier
         , lo.message AS message 
    FROM ps_orders o 
    LEFT JOIN `ps_lengow_orders` lo 
          ON ( o.id_order = lo.id_order ) 
    WHERE marketplace NOT IN('pixplace') 
    OR    marketplace IS NULL 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT oo.id_order AS id_order
         , oo.date_add AS date_add
         , loo.marketplace AS marketplace
         , loo.carrier AS carrier
         , oo.current_state AS state
         , loo.message AS message 
    FROM ps_orders oo 
    RIGHT JOIN ps_lengow_orders loo 
          ON ( oo.id_order = loo.id_order ) 
    ) AS id_order  
WHERE date_add > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), interval 3 DAY) 
AND   (carrier IS NULL 
OR    carrier!='shipped by cdiscount') 
AND   id_order NOT IN (12341,12340,12056,12055,...) 
AND   state = 2 
AND   id_order IN (12669,12668,12667,...) 
ORDER BY id_order DESC'
```

Comment: Strip out the PHP or whatever that code is and give us the "raw" query - use `$sql_query = 'SELECT DISTINCT....`, then `print $sql_query` (or whatever...).

Comment: Also add table definitions, including any keys/indexes, and an idea of the size of each table (you say "10 million" but how many are in each of `orders` and `lengow_orders`?). A view of the query plan used would help too (you don't say which DB engine you are using so I can't tell you how to get that). My first thought is that none of your filtering clauses aside from state=2 are sargable so full table scans are happening, but we need the extra information before looking at the problem in depth.

Comment: I edited the question and placed sql without code php

Comment: @DavidSpillett we are using mysql InnoDB

Comment: @HoussemMaamria - in order to let a user know you've done something, you can let them know by using `@<user_handle>` - i.e. in my case `@Vérace`...

Comment: OK - good stuff. You've removed the excess PHP code - now, maybe get rid of it altogether? It doesn't appear to add anything to the query? Second, you haven't mentioned your server (Oracle, MySQL.. whatever) - that can be a help. Also, the cardinality of your `IN`s and your `NOT IN`s may be an issue. Could you make them tables and `JOIN` instead? Give us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE ps_orders\G` (MySQL syntax - give us the equivalent for your server!).

Answer (score 0):

Indexing is not used on a derived table while executing a query. So below query should return as smaller count as we can do otherwise outer where condition needs to check on each row of derived table. You can achieve it by putting outer where condition inside derived table query if it's possible. for example 'carrier IS NULL' here carrier is in lengow_orders table. In Left join it's always null and in Right join you need to verify it so you can put this condition in right join subquery and it will not affect your output and it will use indexing.

```
 SELECT COUNT(0) 
 FROM            ( 
                      SELECT    o.id_order      AS id_order, 
                                o.date_add      AS date_add, 
                                o.current_state AS state, 
                                lo.marketplace  AS marketplace, 
                                lo.carrier      AS carrier, 
                                lo.message      AS message 
                      FROM      ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'orders o 
                      LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'lengow_orders` lo 
                      ON        ( 
                                          o.id_order = lo.id_order ) 
                      WHERE     marketplace NOT IN(\'pixplace\') 
                      OR        marketplace IS NULL 
                      UNION ALL 
                      SELECT     oo.id_order      AS id_order, 
                                 oo.date_add      AS date_add, 
                                 loo.marketplace  AS marketplace, 
                                 loo.carrier      AS carrier, 
                                 oo.current_state AS state, 
                                 loo.message      AS message 
                      FROM       ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'orders oo 
                      RIGHT JOIN ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'lengow_orders loo 
                      ON         ( 
                                            oo.id_order = loo.id_order ) ) AS id_order
```